# Binding IList to a Chart

Tags: c#, data-binding, charts, ienumerable

I have the following situation:

```
class DataPoint
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this class that implements a list of DataPoints

```
class TrendData : ICollection<DataPoint>, IList<DataPoint>
{
  // Full Interface implementation
}
```

Now, I would like to bind multiple `TrendData` (is `List<TrendData>` a good choice?) objects to a Chart control.

I have tried all binding combinations available, but no luck. I'm sure there is a way to do that, but I just can't figure out what is missing.

Can you guys help me?

Best Regards,
Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Put button and chart on form and check this out.

The bad news is that you have to call the bind function every time you change something in your trend data.

For real-time updates I would stick with chart.datasource, but I have no idea how to combine it with your classes at the moment (and if it's possible that way at all)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace chart_binding
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TrendData td = new TrendData();
    TrendData td2 = new TrendData();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //trend data 1
        DataPoint dt1 = new DataPoint();
        dt1.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        dt1.Value = 100;
        DataPoint dt2 = new DataPoint();
        dt2.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1);
        dt2.Value = 200;

        td.Add(dt1);
        td.Add(dt2);

        //trend data 2
        DataPoint dt11 = new DataPoint();
        dt11.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        dt11.Value = 50;
        DataPoint dt22 = new DataPoint();
        dt22.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1);
        dt22.Value = 70;

        td2.Add(dt11);
        td2.Add(dt22);

        chart1.Series.Add("series2");

        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(td.Select(x => x.DateTime).ToList<DateTime>(), td.Select(x => x.Value).ToList<double>());
        chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(td2.Select(x => x.DateTime).ToList<DateTime>(), td2.Select(x => x.Value).ToList<double>());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //trend data1
        DataPoint dt3 = new DataPoint();
        dt3.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
        dt3.Value = 300;

        td.Add(dt3);

        //trend data2
        DataPoint dt33 = new DataPoint();
        dt33.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
        dt33.Value = 150;

        td2.Add(dt33);
        //no auto-update, have to call this code every time you add something to TrendData
        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(td.Select(x => x.DateTime).ToList<DateTime>(), td.Select(x => x.Value).ToList<double>());
        chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(td2.Select(x => x.DateTime).ToList<DateTime>(), td2.Select(x => x.Value).ToList<double>());
    }
}

class DataPoint
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

class TrendData : IList<DataPoint>
{
    public List<DataPoint> myPoints = new List<DataPoint>();

    public void Add(DataPoint item)
    {
        myPoints.Add(item);
    }

    public int IndexOf(DataPoint item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, DataPoint item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DataPoint this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(DataPoint item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(DataPoint[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(DataPoint item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<DataPoint> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myPoints.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```